# Trying to combine two parts of VBA coding into one

Tags: excel, vba

First let me say that I am freshly new to VBA coding. My spreadsheet has 8 tabs(1 hidden and 1's a chart). Of the other 6 tabs, I would like the code to be able to run on them as well, I just don't know how. I have two sets of code and I am trying to combine them. They are event related codes. I can get them both to run separately but only on a specified sheet. I'm testing them on the "New" tab. The first code sorts the rows after the date is entered into column "H". The other code will cut and paste the entire row into the corresponding tab based on a selection from the drop down list in column "O". I created a call function for both however, only the first code will do anything. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngChng As Range

Set rngChng = Intersect(Target, Range("H:H"))

If rngChng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call AutoSort(rngChng)

Set rngChng = Intersect(Target, Range("O:O"))
If rngChng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Call CopyNPaste(rngChng)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub AutoSort(rngChng As Range)
    Range("A2:O1000").Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub

Sub CopyNPaste(rngChng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "New" Then
        If ws.Name = Target Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=x1Up
        End If
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What are values in Column O, are they sheet names ?

Comment: In `CopyNPaste` sub, `Target` does not mean anything... Should it be `rngChng.Value`, supposing that @CDP1802 supposition it's true? Do you receive an error? If yes, at which line? I would also suggest to use `Option Explicit` and declare all the used variable...

Comment: The reason the second code does not run with a change in column "O" is because if the intersection with "H:H" is nothing (which it is with column O change) the sub exits.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes the values in column O are the sheet names.

Comment: @FaneDuru So when I set the rngChng the second time, it is not setting the target? The target should be rngChng,Value. Also, I do get an error when that code runs. FIrst, the error was a Type Mismatch but then later it changed to an Object Required error. This occurs at line "If ws.Name = Target Then".

Comment: @Shay: `Target` has a meaning only on the event where it is declared in its definition (ex: `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`).  Its scope has been lost when the code goes in another sub. In your case, its replacement is `rngChng`. But what variable declaration did you change, in what type? You must only replace the `Target` with `rngChng` in all places where it appears. Use `rngChng .Value` only where I previously recommended it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the same code from many sheets move the code to a module. Use insert->module on the menu bar, if there are no others it will be named Module1.
In each relevant sheet add the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Call Module1.sortOrCopy(Target)
End Sub
```

Put the sortOrCopy sub in the module. I would suggest using the Target.column 
value rather than Intersections to control the program flow. 
Put the target.cells.count check once at the start. Pass parameters to your 2 subs.

```
Sub sortOrCopy(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Target.Parent

    If Target.Column = 8 Then ' col H
        Call AutoSort(ws)
    ElseIf Target.Column = 15 Then ' col O
        Call CopyNPaste(Target)
    End If

End Sub
```

For the AutoSort sub the only parameter required is the sheet which will be Target.parent. 
You can set the sort range rather than hard coding it using .end(xlUp.row as you have in the other sub.

```
Sub AutoSort(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim iLastRow As Long
    ' last row of sort range
    iLastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A2:O" & iLastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

For the sub CopyNPaste, pass the Target so that the source,row and destination can be determined.
Try to structure the code in simple steps by not doing too much in one line. If the code doesn't work as expected it is easier then to add debug.print or msgBox statements at the various steps. Comment out the If .. End if you don't want user confirmation of the change.

```
Sub CopyNPaste(Target)

    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet, iInsertRow As Long, text As String
    Set wsCopyTo = Sheets(Target.Value)
    ' find last row on CopyTo sheet, insert below
    iInsertRow = 1 + wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    text = "Copy line to sheet " & wsCopyTo.Name & " row " & iInsertRow
    If MsgBox(text, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         With Target.EntireRow
            .Copy wsCopyTo.Range("A" & iInsertRow)
            .Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
         End With
    End If
End Sub
```